# Getting slider to function on Shopify page

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, shopify

---

I'm building a shopify site for a friend and can't get the image slider to function properly. My best guess is that I'm loading js and/or jquery files in the wrong order or else there is a conflict I can't figure out.

The site is http://t25cl.myshopify.com/ and the slider is the fullscreen pic at the top.

I'm trying to use this responsive slider: http://responsiveslides.com/

and here is my code... in the header:

```
{{ 'responsiveslides.css'         | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{{ 'responsiveslides.min.js'     | asset_url | script_tag }}


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for the slider:

```
<div class="twelve columns">
<section>
<ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
<li><img src="{{ 'party-night-waith-dance.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}"></li>
<li><img src="{{ 'confetti_party-1320.jpg' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ shop.name }}"></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
```

and before the closing /body tag:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides();
});
</script>
<script>
// You can also use "$(window).load(function() {"
$(function () {

// Slideshow 1
$("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
auto: true,
maxwidth: 800,
speed: 500
});
});
</script>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. I'm pulling my hair out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because you are overwriting jquery.

[image]

- First request jQuery is loaded
- Second request the plugin is loaded
- Third request jQuery is overwritten by an older version (therefore discarding the plugin with $)

Answer (score 0):

You must add jquery before the slider `responsiveslides.min.js`.

Comment: Thanks Aadil. I just moved the jquery script above the js, but it didn't make any difference.